# How to Fire Windows Service stop event on System restart?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services

I have written Windows Service in VC++ to mount Drives on System restart.
Now when i restart the system, on system shutdown i want to fire my service stop event which is not getting fired.

I have set Windows service properties as automatic but it does not work.
When i manually click on stop button stop event get fired.

Any help is apprecaited.
My code looks like :

```
void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode)
{
  switch(Opcode)
  {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE: 
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_PAUSED;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

     Disconnect() ;// This method i want to get called on system shot down automatically.

      SetServiceStatus (m_ServiceStatusHandle,&m_ServiceStatus);
      bRunning=false;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
      break; 
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straight forward.
Either handle the SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN in your current callback handler function by adding another case to the switch statement. Probably something like:

```
void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD Opcode)
{
  switch(Opcode)
  {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE: 
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_PAUSED;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
      m_ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint = 0;

     Disconnect() ;// This method i want to get called on system shot down automatically.

      SetServiceStatus (m_ServiceStatusHandle,&m_ServiceStatus);
      bRunning=false;
      break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
      break; 

    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        Disconnect();
        break;
  }
  return;
}
```

OR:

Instead of registering the callback function with RegisterServiceCtrlHandler use RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx. This new callback method is preferred. Your callback function's signature needs to match [HandlerEx, see MSDN for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

```
DWORD WINAPI HandlerEx(
  __in  DWORD dwControl,
  __in  DWORD dwEventType,
  __in  LPVOID lpEventData,
  __in  LPVOID lpContext
);
```

Add another case to your switch statement, either SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN (not available on XP/Server 2003)  or SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN, read the warnings about handling these notifications in the HandlerEx documentation referenced above.