# How to Fire Windows Service start event?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services

From the thread - [Fire windows service stop event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269285/how-to-fire-windows-service-stop-event-on-system-restart) I know how to fire an event whenever a system service has stopped.

Now I want to fire an event when a service starts. But I can't find any service control code relating service starting. Is there anther way to implement it?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need service start event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `NotifyServiceStatusChange`

> Enables an application to receive notification when the specified
>   service is created or deleted or when its status changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684276(v=vs.85).aspx

> SERVICE_NOTIFY_START_PENDING (0x00000002) - Report when the service is
>   starting. The hService parameter must be a handle to the service.

You could also use WMI:

[How can I monitor status changes of windows services under windows xp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189815/how-can-i-monitor-status-changes-of-windows-services-under-windows-xp)